# Unable to infer schema for Parquet only on Scheduled Job Run

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I am running a notebook that executes other notebooks through the `dbutils.notebooks.run()` command. Whenever I run this job manually it executes without any issues. Whenever the job runs nightly the ephemeral notebook runs returns the error

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Unable to infer schema for
>   Parquet. It must be specified manually.;

Some other notebooks that ran into the error I was able to resolve by increasing the number of workers on the cluster. I've tried doing that on this workflow as well without any luck, and I can't find any documentation that indicates that should be necessary anyway.

Any insight would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the number of works on the cluster pool fixed the problem. Not certain the correct number of workers needed per ephemeral run, it would seem the minimum of 2 per run would needed, and they are necessarily returned immediately when the run is completed.